# Forks are spawned on a single core on interactive HPC node

Tags: r, parallel-processing, fork, hpc, slurm

I am trying to test a script I have developed locally on an interactive HPC node, and I keep running in this strange issue that `mclapply` works only on a single core. I see several R processes spawned in `htop` (as many as the number of the cores), but they all occupy only one core.

Here is how I obtain the interactive node:

```sh
srun -n 16 -N 1 -t 5 --pty bash -il
```

Is there a setting I am missing? How can I make this work? What can I check?

P.S. I just tested and the other programs that rely on forking to do parallel processing (say `pigz`) are afflicted by the same issue as well. Those that rely on MPI and messaging work properly, it seems.

Comment: Can you try ```results<-do.call("rbind", mclapply(sample_numbers , is_prime,mc.cores=3))``` and see if it improves computation time? I have been using ```mclapply``` on a Linux HPC and never had any issue.

Comment: Tried it. The same issue. No matter how many cores I set in the parameters, only one gets busy.

Comment: That's really weird. No clue man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are missing a setting. Try:

```sh
srun -N 1 -n 1 -c 16 -t 5 --pty bash -il
```

The problem is that you are running the parallel commands within a bash shell that is allocated on a single core, so the bash process is spawned on only one of the cores requested by `srun`.

Otherwise, you can first allocate your resources using `salloc` and once you obtain them run your actual command. For instance:

```sh
salloc -N 1 -n 1 -c 16 -t 5
srun pigz file.ext
```